# How can I consistently jump over the water near the end of Toad's Factory?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

The world record holders do it every time - I was able to do it once. What is a consistent way to do it?  It is so easy to fall in the water...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to hit the first speed bump as fast as you can, and try to use your momentum to carry you over the water to the other side.  Make sure you're hitting the bump as far to the right as you can, and just before you clear the top of the bump, make a hard right, to point you in the proper direction.

---

This maneuver is **extremely** difficult to do, so don't feel too bad if you don't get it for a while.  :)